# Is there a way to search for specific text on a website using the requests library?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a script that will tell me the number of views a given YouTube video has. I know that I can grab all of the existing text on a page but I am curious if there is a way to get it to only output the amount of views the video has, and how I might go about implementing that. Thanks!

Comment: Look for "beautifulsoup".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

requests library will only get you the page's content. You'll need HTML parse like BeautifulSoup to parse and get whatever information you need from the content.